# Why does Visual Studio 2010 keep adding a "reference to self" in my class library?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference

Sometimes, VS wont let me do edit and continue, and it turns out it's because my project `Eric.Controls` has a reference to `Eric.Controls`. It's a project reference, which I never added. Steps to reproduce are inconsistent, but generally, i think it happens when I use the designer and add a control from a different project which I reference.

This occasionally also causes me to be unable to compile at all until I restart Visual Studio which has the target executable locked.

First of all, why would VS even allow a project to reference itself?

Any ideas?

I'm happy to answer any questions which could lead to an answer.

Comment: Pure speculation, (hence a comment and not an answer) but have you somehow managed to construct a circular reference? I.e. does the project that provides the control directly or indirectly reference Eric.Controls? I think Visual Studio should stop you from doing this, but perhaps it's possible if one of the assemblies involved is referenced by file rather than by project?

Comment: Good thought, but no, i've checked. VS won't allow that when you compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer!

If you use solution folders, and you have your project that contains the control in a solution folder, when you drag a control from the toolbox on, it adds the reference to that library.

Solution: don't put control libraries in solution folders.

Answer (score 6):

Yeah, I've noticed this too.  It is is a visual studio bug:  http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/613502/automatically-add-self-reference

It happens when you drag something onto a designer from the toolbox.  To work around it just delete the self reference.

Comment: Yep, looks like it's just a VS.Crap bug. Oh well. I wish it wouldn't do that!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case, the designer was to blame.
The designer added sometimes file references to my projects. Especially when DataBinding and Forms is used.

P.S.: The file references displayed by namespace and project references are displayed by project name in the references folder.